# How to load only a batch of images at a time in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pickle

I am reading cifar100 images from [here](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) and I want to read the images in batches from the pickle file. With this code that I am using this line (Loaded %d examples." % num) loads all the images present in the training dataset. Then using tf.data i can read batches. But when it loads all the images my memory gets utilised and it does not even start the training. I am using something similar to [this](https://github.com/denocris/cifar10-CNN-TensorFlow-Estimators/blob/master/cifar10_5cnn.py). This link uses tfrecords and I want to read cifar data using pickle. So does anyone know how I can read only batches of data from cifar100 pickle file so that my memory does not become full ?

```
def read_data():
    def in_data():
        all_images = []
        all_labels = []
        with open("%s%s" % ("./data/cifar-100-python/", "train"),"rb") as fo:
            dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='latin1')
            images = np.array(dict['data'])
            labels = np.array(dict['fine_labels'])
            num = images.shape[0]

            # images = normalize(images)
            images = images.astype(dtype=np.float32)
            labels = labels.astype(dtype=np.int32)
            images = np.reshape(images, [num, 3, 32, 32])
            images = np.transpose(images, [0, 2, 3, 1])

            print("Loaded %d examples." % num)
            #print('BeforeLables: ', labels)
            labels = one_hot_encode(labels)
            #print('afterLables: ', labels)
            all_images.append(images)
            all_labels.append(labels)
            # print('SIZE:', len(all_images))

        all_images = np.concatenate(all_images)
        all_labels = np.concatenate(all_labels)
        self.size = len(all_images)
        img_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_images).batch(2)
        label_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_labels).batch(2)

        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((img_dataset, label_dataset)).repeat(None)

        images, labels = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
        print('image Shape:',images.shape)
        return images, labels
    return in_data
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you read [tutorial about importing data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#decoding_image_data_and_resizing_it). There is very useful and very similar example. In the example, we don't embed image data to computation graph with from_tensor_slice. Instead we embed file names to the graph.

Moreover if your data was a single too big data to load, you had to split preliminarily it to multiple files

Comment: hey Saket, thank you for the reply. I am new to tensorflow and not quite sure how I can split the pickle file. I tried searching online on how to do that but I was not able to find anything related to it. if you know can you give me some pointers? Because for cifar-100 they do not have any filenames separately.

Comment: CIFAR-100 is not big. Why do you think memory is exhausted?

Comment: Like when I am printing this line Loaded %d examples it tells me 50000 examples loaded. So it is loading the entire dataset, but I figured out on how to load a single file at a time. I used tfRecordLengthDataset and it worked out.
Thank you for the pointer in your earlier reply it worked out.